# How to Complete a Two Key Animation with One Key

Tags: keyboard

I have a game where I need to perform an action by pressing `U` and `K` at the same time, but I also want it to be accomplished by only using one key, because pressing both at the same time ties up your hand a bit.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe you can walk us through the steps on what you want? It's not really clear to me at least. The player needs to press U and K? What does "using one key to input the animation" mean?

Comment: I need to press U and K at the same time to basically. U = block, K = power, but if you press both at the same time and hold them, then you do a power block in the game. It ties up your hands a bit, so I want to just press one key to function like U+K. I want to be able to use something like "O" and it function like I pressed U and K.

Answer (score 4):

This is pretty simple. Basically, you just have another key call the same function as U+K does.

```
if((keyDown('U') && keyDown('K')) || keyDown('O'))
    doPowerBlock();
```

Basically that's saying if the U key AND the K key are pressed, OR the O key, do the action. Or depending on how you have things arranged, you could do something like:

```
if((keyDown('U'))
    doBlock();

if((keyDown('K'))
    doPower();

if((keyDown('O')) {
    doBlock();
    doPower();
}
```